# confusion about different ways to represent a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I just read from a  discrete math book that says that a point on the number line is also a representation of a number, and we can picture the set of real numbers as the set of all points on a line (which is the number line). I also recently learned that a line is not a set of points, so I just imagine it as a bunch of points lying on the number line as the set of all real numbers. However, if a set contains only 1 number, can we represent it as a point on the number line? And can a bunch of things(points, numbers, etc...) considered to be a set, or does it takes something more(maybe a big circle or 2 rosters around them) for a bunch of things to be considered as a set?

Comment: The idea of the [real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_line) is that we can associate to a real number a point on the line using the number as the [coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) for the corresponding point.

Comment: In mathematics, we can "collect together" mathematical objects: numbers, points, lines, etc. to form *sets* of... The set $\mathbb N$ of all *natural* numbers, the set $\mathbb R$ of all *real* numbers, and so on.

Comment: Also geometrical figures can be define as sets, maybe in an abstract way: in the plane, a *triangle* is a set of **three** non-collinear points.

Comment: "*I learned...we can picture the set of real numbers as the set of all points on a line... I also...learned that a line is not a set of points*"  Anything and everything can be organized in your thoughts however you like so long as it is useful to do so in that way.  If you prefer things as sets, go ahead.  If you prefer things not as sets, so long as you do it in a useful way then that is fine too.  Formally, in most ways of constructing mathematical objects to talk about... *every object* is a set, and most are sets of sets...

Comment: Its ["sets all the way down"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).  Now... "*What does it take for something to be considered a set?*"  Very little.  A set may have zero elements, may have one element, may have any number of elements... finite or otherwise.  Those elements themselves might also be sets or depending on the specific choice of set theory might be an [urelement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement).  In [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), as alluded to, all possible elements of sets are also sets.

Comment: To build intuition, it is common to begin by thinking of numbers as some sort of idealized urelement (*a pure element that does not require a set to define it*) so you can work with simple examples such as $\{1,2,3\}$ without having to think harder about what each of those numbers actually are to familiarize yourself with basic set operations and terminology.  Once you are more comfortable with the basics, then revisit and see [how they might be formally defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Constructions_based_on_set_theory).